# SQL query NOT EXISTS intesad of NOT IN

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having issues finding an appropriate `NOT EXISTS`-Query to replace my `NOT IN` one. I have to replace it because of the nullable-columns problem. However I'm rather new to SQL, so I can't get the right relations.

What I'm trying to do is  to exclude all users that are already assigned to a practice, which do not have the "informal" flag set (in other words: Unassigned users with the informal flag). My current query is

```
SELECT USERS.UserID, USERS.Name
FROM USERS
WHERE USERS.Informal = true AND USERS.UserID NOT IN (
    SELECT USERS.UserID
    FROM PRACTICES
    LEFT JOIN ATTENDS ON PRACTICES.PracticeID = ATTENDS.PracticeID
    LEFT JOIN USERS ON ATTENDS.UserID = USERS.UserID 
    WHERE PRACTICES.PracticeID = 7
)
```

[this is the relevant table structure for the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs0NE.png)

I'd be very grateful if someoune could hint me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ned to repeat the `USERS` table in the subquery -- for either `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS`.  I strongly recommend `NOT EXISTS` (because it handles `NULL` values more intuitively):

```
SELECT u.UserID, u.Name
FROM USERS u
WHERE u.Informal = true AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT USERS.UserID
                  FROM PRACTICES p 
                       ATTENDS a
                       ON p.PracticeID = a.PracticeID 
                  WHERE a.UserID = u.UserID AND p.PracticeID = 7
                 )
```